# Change cell color is cell value is any date

Tags: excel, date, colors, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have a map with data in Excel 2007 and need to have a kind of conditional format to change cell color if the data in the cell is a date. Must work on any date so can't use the "in between" date conditional formula.
Has to give other data another color.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a place to do your work or write your code for you. Try something and we'll help you with that.

Comment: Tried conditional format but have to give a range for the date...
Still google-ing for same problem but can't find any other solution....
That's why i turned to this. I'm no programmer so have no vb-knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "have a map" and you don't mention any specific date format (string or numeric?) but a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=CELL("format",A1)="D1"
```

might suit, with an Applies to range as appropriate.